# Failed at the app@0.0.1 start script. start: `nest start`

Tags: npm, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nestjs

I am deploying NestJs app on elastic beanstalk, after successfull deployment, app is not started and shows error at start script but when I login to Amazon Linux 2 ec2 instance and run node dist/main, it start running and not otherwise with npm start.

Logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.19.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~prestart: unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~start: unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~start: PATH: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.19.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/app/current/node_modules/.bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
9 verbose lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~start: CWD: /var/app/current
10 silly lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '-c', 'nest start' ]
11 silly lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.19.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.19.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd /var/app/current
16 verbose Linux 4.14.200-155.322.amzn2.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v12.19.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1 start: `nest start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the unmudl-backend-app@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: There isn't really much information here as to what could be going on. Are you meaning to use the Nest CLI to start the server? If so, has it been installed?

Comment: yes nest cli has been installed, i want to run with npm start but it shows error with this command but it ran successfully with node dist/main, what's the issue?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  my start script in package.json is nest start but its shows errors on node modules with this command but ran with node dist/main

Comment: All I can assume is that you haven't built the server as well. The above doesn't really say much other than it can't run `nest start` and there's some error due to an `EventEmitter`

Comment: So its an issue with code?

Comment: I'll say it a third time: with what you've provided above, __I can't say__ where the issue is. There's not enough information

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of your `"start"` in package.json to `"npm i -g @nestjs/cli && node dist/main"`

it should look like the following line:

> "start": "npm i -g @nestjs/cli && node dist/main"

and if you are using prisma you will need to do it like:

> "start": "npm i -g @prisma/cli @nestjs/cli && prisma generate && node
> dist/main"